# module resolution error with Nx repository

Tags: angular, node-modules, monorepo, nx-monorepo

Hello (and happy new year),

Using a template for a monorepo provided by the company, i migrated an angular project in the monorepo. I added the needed dependencies before running npm i.
After restarting vscode to allow nx to detect the new app, i tried to run the app using serve.
I get a huge amount of errors in the console, among them:

```
X [ERROR] TS2792: Cannot find module './localize'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? [plugin angular-compiler]

    node_modules/@angular/localize/index.d.ts:9:28:
      9 │ import { ɵLocalizeFn } from './localize';
```

or :

```
    X [ERROR] TS2792: Cannot find module 'rxjs'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'nodenext', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option? [plugin angular-compiler]
    
        apps/digiCompta/src/app/shared/validators/async/compteTva.validator.ts:12:30:
          12 │ import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
```

and even:

```
X [ERROR] TS-991010: 'imports' must be an array of components, directives, pipes, or NgModules.
  Value is of type '[(not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), (not statically analyzable), DownloadButtonComponent]'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    apps/digiCompta/src/app/shared/components/ebp-pdf-viewer/ebp-pdf-viewer.component.ts:34:11:
      34 │   imports: [
```

On multiple files of the project. when i go to thoses files there is no error and the files exist.

I don't understand why i can find theses files but the compiler says it can't find thoses modules. nodeResolution is set to node, module is set to ES2022 in the tsconfig.base.json.

I deleted node modules and .nx files to start fresh, the error persists
my node version is 18.16.0 which should be compatible with angular 17.

is anyone familliar with this?
(note that the same project is working when I migrate it with nxConsole directly....)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution maybe you should set the moduleResolution to nodenext instead of node

Comment: @SirOneOfMany, didn't work. when i set it to bundler it works but breaks the components or services imports. weird

Comment: it seems to work with node, but the imports are broken with src/
Looks like it wants me to use relative imports...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently NX uses relative path. Meaning that is you migrate a project by hand and you have a bunch of 'src/' imports you have to change those.

How ever if you migrate the project using nx-console nx will change all those imports for you.